# Download a 3d mesh from google earth current view

Tags: vb.net, google-earth

Open Google Earth in a particular view.
For above view polygon, Google Earth keeps everything in its database.

1. How to connect to Google Earth via Visual studio vb-net and abstract
   the following for further proceedure :
   View polygon coordinates - 3d geometry (mess) - and View polygon image ?
   Not any answers with : save image either kml.
   MicroStation V8i does it, but never explained the procedure.
   AutoCad with out extensions, not.
2. If no answer available
   In order to create manually a word file, how to estimate an exported Google Earth

image x-axis pixels and y-axis pixels with known image dimensions on Google Earth ?
Furthermore any idea related with getting Google Earth 3d surface ?